# "Get everything together"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Right now my life is kind of in a mess I'm unemployed and barely have a place to live. If I want to tell my friends that I will meet and hang out with them once I sort myself out. Does "get everything together" have a similar meaning? Like "I will shoot you a message once I get everything together".

Comment: Also consider phrases like “once I get everything back on track”,  “once I get my life back on track”, “once I get it all together” or “once I get it all together again”, “once I work it all out”, and “once I get my shit together”.  To my ear,  the latter phrases are more idiomatic than is “get everything together”, which I don't recall ever hearing in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can mean that, but in a weaker sense, it usually means something like, "*once I'm fully prepared*". In the phrase:

> I will shoot you a message once I get everything together.

I'd usually read this as meaning that you need time to prepare a message and I can expect a more complete response at a later date. This would be a perfectly acceptable use of the phrase in a professional or social setting.

Comment: Is "shooting a message" formal or informal?

Comment: @PersianCat It's definitely informal, but I'd say it's acceptable in at least a semi-professional setting. You may want to avoid it at times, but it wouldn't really raise any eyebrows, IMHO.

Comment: What if I were to say this in person, like we've just finished hanging out and I want to say for next time "I will shoot you a message once I get everything together."?

Comment: @Theo I think it implies that there's something in particular that you're trying to 'get together', e.g. you're doing some research, setting up a party, etc. If it's just a casual comment, with no context, it might sound a bit odd. But then again, anything would sound odd without proper context.

Comment: What does *get together* precisely mean?

Comment: It could many things in different contexts (e.g. *I'm going to get together with John tomorrow*), but here it means *to prepare*.